# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error 1005 Cant create table practica.users

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Las migraciones que salieron fue migration y users pero no las otras tablas, y posteo el error que sale.y como coloque los foreign

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, acostumbra agregar el còdigo como texto ya que no es visible para todos los usuarios, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error que obtuviste no tiene relación Laravel en si, de hecho este último lo que esta haciendo es solo mostrar el error que el motor de bases de datos le devuelve como respuesta.

Por otro lado cuando estás creando tablas que se relacionan entre si, como por ejemplo:

- Users
- Roles

Donde un usuario tiene muchos roles y por ende la llave foránea declarada en la tabla roles va a vincularla con la tabla users entonces:

Tu primero debes crear la tabla `Users` para que de esta forma cuando la llave foránea en `Roles` que llamaremos `user_id` trate de hacer la unión con la tabla `Users` esta misma ya exista incluyendo su llave primaria (que en `Users` sería la columna `id`):

Es decir tu declaración (independiente de si es por Laravel o desde el motor de BD) debería para este caso ser así:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...............
);

CREATE TABLE roles(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_roles_users FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Otros puntos a tomar en cuenta:

- Procura que tus llaves primarias y foráneas sean del mismo tipo de dato
- Que además sean de la misma longitud

**Enlaces necesarios de lectura**

- [Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
- [Foreign Keys en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Mmm una pregunta que se me ocurrio, ok un usuario puede tener muchos roles, pero en el caso de que un usuario tenga un solo rol y un rol tenga varios usuarios como seria la creacion? creo primero la tabla rol y luego user?

Comment: @Aisakk la relación que planteas como duda no es lógica pues indicas que un rol puede ser a un solo usuario pero luego dices que un rol tiene muchos usuarios, entonces no no esta bien planteada esa relación, necesitas identificarla bien primero antes de proceder

Comment: es una pregunta nueva xD, y no indico que un rol puede ser un solo usuario, indico que un usuario puede tener un solo rol y un rol tener muchos usuarios, en ese caso se debe crear primero la tabla rol no?

Comment: El camino mas corto para crear esas 2 tablas es que primero hagas la tabla que no tiene la llave foránea y después hagas la tabla donde vas a tener que declarar la llave foránea